# How do I return font-size to normal after it has been set via a percentage?

Tags: css

I have a scenario where a media query is setting font size on body and html elements to 85%. A new piece of work requires that the font sizes do not change when the website goes into mobile breakpoints but setting the font-size to 100% when this happens does not affect the font size despite taking priority.

My question is how can I keep the rule that sets all font sizes to 85% but maintain my font size in a specific place in my website when i reach the breakpoint that triggers the smaller text.

Rule causing smaller text

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
    html, body {font-size: 85%;}
}
```

Rule that  should override it, ignore the fact that it is always on

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) {
    html .subset, body .subset {font-size: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code here ?

Comment: How is that relevant to my question

Comment: font-size:initial works perfectly. If you want to put it as an answer ill accept it

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is because `html .subset` *inherits* the font size of `html` - so the font size is set to *100% of 85%*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font-size: initial;` would set the font-size back to the **initial** size, which is always `100%` or the default `16px`.

```
   @media only screen and (min-width: 0px) {
        html .subset, body .subset {font-size: initial;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Actully Font-size percentage Depented on Current Element parent Font-size**.
example: **Demo** https://codepen.io/sayed021/pen/RyyrJM.

***Your Html and body dose't contain any parent or parent not any font-size.***
when body fontsize 20px; and h1 font-size: 300%; it's work or mens is h1 contain font-size= (20x3)px or 60px.

```css
body {
  font-size: 20px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 300%;
  color: red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) {
   body { font-size: 16px; }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
   body { font-size: 20px; }
}
```

```html
<h1>font size is persentage</h1>
```